# SSL Error "The server's security certificate is revoked!"

Tags: security, ssl, certificate

When I try to open en.wikipedia.org I get following error: "The server's security certificate is revoked!". So far as I check this happens with both Opera and Internet Explorer, but only with this website. Could anyone point me at least where I should look for solution?

Comment: It's not just you, but I have yet to figure it out.  We started seeing this today with another web site (and (https://)en.wikipedia.org is doing it to us as well) -- it works at some locations, but not at others.  For the branches where it's not working, disabling "Check for server certificate revocation" in IE's Advanced properties allows us in, but the strange/confusing part is that in the branches/locations where it works, they have that option enabled...

Comment: So far it seems related to the Internet connection/ISP being used (the areas that don't work are with one ISP, and the areas that do are with another).

Comment: Please provide the certificate information the browser is using.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Problem is gone. Thx ... whoever did it ;)

Comment: Yeah it started working for me as well at all locations.  screwy.. Unfortunately it didn't fix our problem with the original site we were testing again.  Weird stuff. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to have been a transient error outside of anyone's control (except maybe Wikipedia's).

Answer (score 1):

The issuer of the certificate unfortunately messed something up so that it might happen that certificates get reported as revoked which are not revoked at all. See [GlobalSign screw-up cancels top websites' HTTPS certificates](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/10/13/globalsigned_off/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Steffen Ullrich this was caused by an error by GlobalSign. If the affected websites do not take action, you could be blocked for four days.

Use the following command to remove the erroneous entries from the Windows Cache

```
certutil -urlcache * delete
```

https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1353318-view-and-or-delete-crl-ocsp-cache

Comment: Except clearing the cache doesn't fix it. IE still determines it's bad, causing it to not even bother caching it.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It worked for me. You must be experiencing a diferent scenario.